# PHP returns false but $.post receives as true

Tags: php, jquery

I was looking in the internet but actually i wasn't successful, so I try it here :)

I have a jquery function like:

```
var arr = [];
$.post('my.php',{
      data:  arr
     }).done(function(response){
        console.log(response);
       alert('successful');
     }).fail(function(response){
       console.log(response);
       alert('failure');
});
```

My php looks like

```
$bOk = false; //preset
//...
return $bOk; // actually returns false here for testing
```

These are code samples, but in fact that's what it does.

Why does `return false` doesn't call `.fail()` ?

If i have kind of php errors it calls `.fail()`

**Is there something i have to do to call the `.fail()` function ?**

Comment: Don't return a HTTP 200 status. `.done()` just means the call is finished. You should be checking the response for an error code of some kind.

Comment: returning outside of a function doesn't do anything significant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.fail()` is used for HTTP errors. If you were to do something like `header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");` it should trigger the FAIL. But currently, it returns with a `200 OK message` because it gets the response from the server.

Try either Implementing the 404 response, or in the `.success()` call, check whether or not the response contains the false response.

Edit.

It should be noted, that the response I have given as an example (404) may not be the most appropriate (it depends on the circumstances of your application).

Check this link here for the list of HTTP status codes, and decide what is your most valid. 
Most likely, looking into the 400 and 500 range.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: Not a `404 not found` status-code! The page witch handles the POST is there.

Comment: It should be noted, 404 was used as an example; and is probably not the most valid response; check the list of valid HTTP responses here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: And that list has to be inside of your answer

Comment: @AndreasFurster Even though the script that handles the request is there, doesn't mean 404 is wrong; it simply means that the requested resource wasn't there ... and that has a meaning in RESTful design.

Comment: @AndreasFurster 404 may be a perfectly valid response, it depends on the context of the application. For example, if the ajax request was to get a content from a dynamic page (as defined as part of hte POST request), then 404 Not Found is valid if the page isnt found instead of false etc. Added the list into my account

Comment: Ok, agree with your statements. But in the beginning the answer was: Just use 404...

Comment: @Dwza Please accept the answer if this is fixed your problem. Thanks

Comment: i was about to do this, but there is a time restriction of 15min. according to you 67 points, you propably don't know this :D i will accept in 2 mins

Answer (score 0):

The fail callback should be used as fail callback, so only if something really fail.

In your case, you could return an error code, so on the success callback you will do something like this:

```
var arr = [];
$.post('my.php',{
    data:       arr
}).done(function(response){
    if(response==2){
     alert('password is invalid');
     return;
    }
    console.log(response);
    alert('successful');

}).fail(function(response){

    alert('An unexpected error occurs, please contact the administrator if this error persist.');

});
```

If you still wanted to do the login on the fail callback, on that case yes you need to return an http status, using http_response_code php function like this:

```
http_response_code(404);
```

Comment: actually i delete a file by `unlink($filename);` and catch the result in a loop so if file could not be found or deleted the loop stops. its an error because some happened. still there is only a true or false :) thought i could send this to fail but i understood now ^^

Comment: In that case, send a number: 0 or 1, on the response check response==1 or response==2, but all this will always happen inside the success callback.

Answer (score -1):

### false does not returns http error.

**if you want to return http error for reach in .fail() use following code**

```
if ($everything_is_ok)
    {
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        print json_encode($result);
    }
else
    {
        header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Booboo');
        header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
        die(json_encode(array('message' => 'ERROR', 'code' => 1337)));
    }
```

Comment: actually i don't want to send a error :) but thx for this answere